# ApacheOpenOffice won't allow me to save to flash drive or network

Tags: openoffice.org

I click save in Apache openoffice I don't see a way to save to external media. Going up a level only takes me as far as the hard drive will go.

Comment: Search the `/media` folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go up all the way (to `/`)

[image]

[image]

Open `media/<USERNAME>/<DEVICENAME>` then save it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

The same applies to Libre Office

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the external media is otherwise accessible (i.e., attached and successfully mounted), depending on what version of Ubuntu you're running, it is probably accessible at:

- `/media/username/volumename`, *or*
- especially in older versions of Ubuntu, `/media/volumename`.

Replace **`username`** with your actual username and *`volumename`* with the volume's label (or UUID if it has no label).

In practice, all you likely have to do is **go up as high as you can in the folder hierarchy, then go into the folder called `media`.** It will be somewhere in there, and usually there are only a few things there, so you should be able to find it.

---

Ubuntu, like other Unix-like operating systems, mounts all filesystems in the same directory hierarchy. Everything is somewhere under [`/`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_directory). Empty folders<sup>**1**</sup> serve as [mount points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_(computing)#MOUNT-POINT), where other filesystems (which may even be on other physical disks) are [attached](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_(Unix)).

This is sometimes confusing to users familiar with OSes that do it differently, such as Windows. (In Windows, filesystems *may* be mounted anywhere, but in practice are usually assigned their own drive letters.)

In Ubuntu, removable media are most commonly mounted somewhere inside `/media`. This usually happens automatically when you connect an external device.

<sub>**1**: Well, they *should* be empty--otherwise things get confusing. You don't have to worry about that though, unless you're manually mounting filesystems with the [`mount`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/mount.8.html) command. Automatic mounts that happen when you plug a drive into your computer are always on empty folders created automatically during the mounting process.</sub>